# How to generate Python code of GUI created under Taurusdesigner or Qt?

Tags: python, qt, user-interface, pyqt4

First of all let me tell you that I am new to Qt and also to Python.

I am using Qt(Taurusdesigner) to create my GUIs.
After starting Qt(Taurusdesigner), I generate my python code for that particular GUI using:

```
taurusuic4 -x -o file.py file.ui
or
pyuic4 -x -o file.py file.ui
```

After executing this command on command line I am able to generate python file, but the auto generated classes looks like:

```
class MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
```

Where as when I am searching for any help on Google I find class written like:

```
class MainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
```

What would I do to generate 2nd type of class file using Qt(Taurusdesigner)??

Why there is a syntax difference in my class and class which are written for help on internet.
Please Help regarding this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you are confused about class, object and methods, I'd suggest reading a tutorial, for example [this one](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_classes_objects.htm)

Answer (score 1):

The ui module generated by `taurusuic4/pyuic4` should be imported into your main application. You do not need to use the `-x` option, and obviously you should choose a better module name than "file":

```
taurusuic4 -o mainwindow.py file.ui
```

Your main application module should look something like this:

```
from PyQt4.QtGui import QMainWindow
from mainwindow import Ui_MainWindow

class MainWindow(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.handleButton)

    def handleButton(self):
        print('Hello World!')
```

This approach means that all the widgets from Qt(Taurus) Designer end up as attributes of the `MainWindow` class. Another approach is to have the ui elements within a separate namespace:

```
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.handleButton)
```

Answer (score 0):

`setupUI` and `__init__` are two methods of the class `MainWindow`. For one class, there can be any number of method and you can put them in whatever order you like.

There is always an `__init__` method, it's called a constructor. This method is called when you create an object (for example when you do `myWindow=MainWindow()`). It's usually put at the beginning because it'll be call first. Specifically for QT, you have to call the parent's constructor with `super`.

`setupUI` is the method created by your designer, to take care of layout and such. It should be called in the constructor.

Your code should look like:

```
class MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        #code made by the designer

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        #some code

   def another_method(self):
        #some more code
```